# How to get the parent form of an application?

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child

I created a methods in a "Cammon" class. This method's functionality is to check a setting variable, from there it open the correct form as a MID child.

Here is my method

```
   public static void OpenMyForm(string sectionName, string[] keys, Form myform) {
        //make sure there are no other forms of the ame type open
        foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) {
            if (form.GetType() == myform.GetType()) {
                form.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (Settings._AuthenticationMode == "Thumbprint") {

            var newMDIChild = myform;

            // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
            newMDIChild.MdiParent = Main.ActiveForm;

            // Display the new form.
            newMDIChild.Show();
        }


        if (Settings._AuthenticationMode == "Single" && UserInfo.Autherized == true) {

            var role = new Roles();

            if (role.hasAccess(sectionName, keys)) {
                var newMDIChild = myform;

                // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
                newMDIChild.MdiParent = Main.ActiveForm;

                // Display the new form.
                newMDIChild.Show();
            }
            else {
                Common.Alert("You do not have a permissions to perform this action!");
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue here is when I call this method I get the exception error bellow.

However, when I call this method the new forms actually open just before I get the error.

I believe the issue is in the line below

```
newMDIChild.MdiParent = Main.ActiveForm;
```

I believe the way I am setting the parent is incorrect. The parent form name in Main()

Here is an example of how I am calling this method

```
Common.OpenMyForm("Vendors", new string[] { "add" }, new DepartmentsAdd());
```

How can I correct this issue?

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Telerik.WinControls.UI
  StackTrace:
       at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListElement.HandleMouse(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadListElement.OnBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseRoutedEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.RaiseBubbleEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.RaiseRoutedEvent(RadElement sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.DoMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.ComponentInputBehavior.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadPopupControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at RM.Program.Main()
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: ActiveForm is the form that has currently the focus, if any. Thus might be another MDI child and not the main form. I usually make use of an ApplicationContext class to setup my Mainform and other related context details.

Comment: @NeillVerreynne Can you please explain how that is done? I am not sure how to do that. I am new to C# a detailed answered in appreciated

Comment: you can google, there are lots of links how to use ApplicationContext. For example: http://etutorials.org/Programming/visual-c-sharp/Part+III+Programming+Windows+Forms/Chapter+11+An+Introduction+to+Windows+Forms/Controlling+a+Windows+Forms+Application/

Comment: I belive I understand what is ApplicationContext class, but I am not sure how to assign the MainForm to be the parent and how do I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement you application context class that derives from ApplicationContext:

```
class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
{
  public static MyApplicationContext CurrentContext;

   public MyApplicationContext(Form mainForm) : base(mainForm)
   {
     //...implement any hooks, additional context etc.

     CurrentContext = this;
   }
}
```

Implementation to use your application context:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) 
{

  var context = new MyApplicationContext(new MainForm());

   // Run the application with the specific context.
   Application.Run(context);

 }
```

To access your application context data like the MainForm:

```
MyApplicationContext.CurrentContext.MainForm
```

Thus:

```
// Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
newMDIChild.MdiParent = MyApplicationContext.CurrentContext.MainForm;
```

Comment: @NeilVerreynne  thank you so much for the answer. I have updated my code but it is still not working. I still get an error when the MID child open and it point me back to             `var appCtx = new MyApplicationContext(new Main());
            Application.Run(appCtx);` line inside the Program.cs file

Comment: Are you assigning the .MdiParent using the static variable of your application context? Are you getting the same error? Also, the stacktrace shows that it fails on a Telerik control. It also could be that any events that you have hooked up are firing and executing your code which reference instances which are not instantiated yet.

Comment: it actually worked. another line of code was causing the issue. Thank you so much